# Is it possible to use OpenEdge Architect with Eclipse 3.7.x?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, progress-4gl, openedge

Currently we are using Eclipse 3.4.2. And would like to use Jira plugin for Eclipse, but it needs at least version 3.6.x. It is impossible to update 3.4.x to 3.7.x. We will need to install a new version of Eclipse. 
But how do I 'make' OpenEdge from freshly installed Eclipse? From Google search results I can see that there seems to be OpenEdge 10.2b plugin. But where do I get it? And is it going to be the same as what I have now (OpenEdge Architect 10.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in in $DLC/oeide for a script called integrateArchitect - if it's there, that's how you can take a current OEA install and integrate it with another eclipse installation.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it and it tells me that 3.7.0 version is not supported.